# Trouble with pyplot displaying resized images in python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

This is my first stack overflow question so please correct me if its not a good one:

I am currently processing a bunch of grayscale images as numpy ndarrays (dtype=uint8) in python 2.7. When I resize the images using `resized=misc.imresize(image,.1)`, the resulting image will sometimes show up with different gray levels when I plot it with pyplot. Here is what my code looks like. I would post an image of the result, but I do not have the reputation points yet:

```
import cv2
from scipy import misc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image=cv2.imread("gray_image.tif",cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
resize=misc.imresize(image,.1)
plt.subplot(1,2,1),plt.imshow(image,"gray")
plt.subplot(1,2,2),plt.imshow(resize,"gray")
plt.show()
```

If I write the image to a file, the gray level appears normal.
If I compare the average gray level using numpy:
`np.average(image)` and `np.average(resized)`,
the average gray level values are about the same, as one would expect. 
If I display the image with cv2.imshow, the gray level appears normal.

Its not only an issue with resizing the image, but the gray level also gets screwy when I add images together (when most of one image is black and shouldn't darken the resulting image), and when I build an image pixel-by-pixel such as in:

```
import numpy as np
image_copy = np.zeros(image.shape)
for row in range(image.shape[0]):
    for col in range(image.shape[1]):
        image_copy[row,col]=image[row,col]
plt.imshow(image_copy,"gray") #<-- Will sometimes show up darker than original image
plt.show()
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be going on?

I apologize for the wordiness and lack of clarity in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imshow` is automatically scaling the color information to fit the whole available range. After resizing, the color range be smaller, resulting in changes of the apparent color (but not of the actual values, which explains why saved images work well).

You likely want to tell `imshow` not to scale your colors. This can be done using the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments as [explained in the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow). You probably want to use something like `plt.imshow(image, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)` to achieve an invariant appearance.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Once I set the vmin and max values to the vmin and max values of the original image the colors showed up the same.

Comment: This might be a different question, but when I apply other operations, such as a Kuwahara filter, or I try to extract pixel values within a certain grayscale range, they use the apparent values rather than the actual values, so this tells me that the problem goes beyond pyplot. Is there another way to address the color scaling?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you open another stack overflow question, preferably with example code and/or images?

Comment: I resolved the issue, but I posted another question anyways since I am not sure why the solution worked. [Here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996863/trouble-with-color-scaling-in-python-misc-imresize).